# Sorting in dplyr produces incorrect output

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

The arrange() in dplyr produces incorrect result.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(name=c("A","B","C","D"), val=c(0.032, 0.077, 0.4, 0.0001)))
x.1 <- x %>% arrange(val)
x.2 <- x %>% arrange(desc(val))
```

The outputs are:

```
   name  val
1    A   0.032
2    B   0.077
3    C   0.4
4    D   1e-04

>x.1
   name  val
1    A   0.032
2    B   0.077
3    C   0.4
4    D   1e-04

> x.2
   name     val
1    D   1e-04
2    C   0.4
3    B   0.077
4    A   0.032
```

Both ascending and descending order sort producing incorrect output.
Not sure what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind())` is what you are doing wrong there.  Everything is converted to character in `cbind()`, and then to factor in `as.data.frame()`.  Use `data.frame()` to create data frames, that's why it's there.

Comment: When you run into these kind of issues, a good practice would be to use `str` to check the classes of your variables. Currently, your variables are factors due to the reason mentioned above

Comment: @RichardScriven Reopened it.  It happens many times to answers that I post as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.data.frame(cbind())` is what you are doing wrong there. Everything is converted to character in `cbind()`, and then to factor in `as.data.frame()`. Have a look ...

```
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
#  $ val : Factor w/ 4 levels "0.032","0.077",..: 1 2 3 4
```

I don't know where people are learning this method of creating data frames, but it's terrible practice and should never be used.

Use `data.frame()` to create data frames, that's why it's there (or when using *dplyr*, there is `data_frame()` as well).

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C","D"), val=c(0.032, 0.077, 0.4, 0.0001))
x.1 <- x %>% arrange(val)
x.2 <- x %>% arrange(desc(val))

x.1
#   name    val
# 1    D 0.0001
# 2    A 0.0320
# 3    B 0.0770
# 4    C 0.4000

x.2
#   name    val
# 1    C 0.4000
# 2    B 0.0770
# 3    A 0.0320
# 4    D 0.0001
```